How can I write two digits on a quad 7-segment display with Arduino?
From a DHT sensor, I'm reading the ambient temperature and my goal is to display the temperature on a quadruple 7-segment display, ending with the letter C for Celsius degrees.
I receive the temperature from the sensor, convert the amount into an array, for example, if it is 19 degrees it would be [1,9], and each number goes to the corresponding display, in the example the 1 would be on display 2 and the 9 on display 3.
I need all digits to be displayed simultaneously; currently they are shown one by one on the corresponding display.
The numbers are represented in this way
    void eight() {
        digitalWrite(A, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(B, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(C, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(F, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(E, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(D, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(G, HIGH);
    }

And this is the code
    void loop() {
        // Display the digits on the 7-segment displays
        for (int i = 0; i < numDigits; ++i) {
            switch (digits[i]) {
                case 0:
                    c();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    one();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    two();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    three();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    four();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    five();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    six();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    seven();
                    break;
                case 8:
                    eight();
                    break;
                case 9:
                    nine();
                    break;
            }

            // Display the current digit on the corresponding display
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    turnOnDisplay2();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    turnOnDisplay3();
                    break;
            }

            // Wait briefly before moving to the next digit
            delay(1000);
            Serial.println(roundedTemperature);
        }

        // Display the letter 'C' on the fourth display
        c();
        turnOnDisplay4();
        delay(1000);
    }

And each display is turned on in this way, for example, this one is to turn on the second:
    void turnOnDisplay2() {
      digitalWrite(digit1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(digit2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(digit3, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(digit4, HIGH);
    }


why not use a library? which one, depends on the wiring of the digits, https://github.com/DeanIsMe/SevSeg could work

It is cleaner to have an array [0..15] of magic constants for each of the valid hex digits that you want to display and load the entire register or at least 8 bits of it in one go. That and a generic write digit D segment N to state S is usually sufficient even for custom hardware. You may well find a library that already does what you want.
